# How to activate numeric keypad on woocommerce checkout fields for mobile users?

Tags: wordpress, mobile, woocommerce, checkout, numeric-keypad

Is it possible to activate number keyboard for mobile user in woocommerce checkout?

I have customized woocommerce default checkout fields and some of these fields are just number (for example:Postal code, Phone, etc.).

Most of my website visitors are mobile users and I want to make the checkout session easier for them by activating numeric keypad for these input fields.

I searched the web and I realized if you add below code,numeric keyboard  will be called automatically.

```html
<input inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

[Finger-friendly numerical inputs with `inputmode`](https://css-tricks.com/finger-friendly-numerical-inputs-with-inputmode/)

But I don't know how can I add this attribute to checkout fields like billing_phone,billing_postcode, or other custom fields which ask for number.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I found a snippet for this question from businessbloomer:

```html
// Change field type to number woocommerce checkout
 
function bbloomer_change_checkout_field_input_type() {
echo "<script>document.getElementById('billing_postcode').type = 'number';</script>";
echo "<script>document.getElementById('billing_city').type = 'number';</script>";       
    
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_change_checkout_field_input_type');
```

[WooCommerce: Change Input Type @ Checkout Fields](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-change-input-type-checkout-fields/)